# Wildfly 11 management integration with KeyCloak over new Elytron subsystem

Tags: security, integration, keycloak, jboss-wildfly-11, elytron

I would like to integrate security for WildFly 11 management interfaces (management console, web console) with KeyCloak over the new Elytron subsystem.

I've been looking the [latest documentation for Wildfly 11](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/WildFly+Elytron+Security) and there is chapter **Using KeyCloak with WildFly Elytron** but is unfortunately empty.

I will be really appreciated if someone could give me some advice how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycloak documentation for version 3.4 is very detailed http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_jboss_adapter - you have to install the adapter for your Elytron subsystem on Wildfly 11 (beware: the CLI is different from the Wildfly 10 version! )

Comment: I'm afraid that in that documentation is just WildFly Adapter for securing applications which runs on WildFly. My concern is to secure WildFly management interface.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some missed QAing it...  Anyways .. i think this can be your starting points.

https://github.com/ssilvert/wildfly/blob/kcauth/keycloak/KeycloakSetup.txt

More details and concepts can be found in this email thread , http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/wildfly-dev/2014-June/002230.html . Sorry these are not complete answers but can be a good starting point to your solution.

Comment: It's really good starting point, that I can dig in more deeply.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation was updated with more information on how to use Keycloak to protect Wildfly Administration Console and Management API.

Take a look here https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Protecting+Wildfly+Adminstration+Console+With+Keycloak.